# Use dedicated Load Balancer for jenkins port 50000

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have installed `jenkins` from its official helm [chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins)

I am exposing it via `nginx` ingress controller, which is also installed via its helm [chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress).

The service is exposed in a public IP that I am passing to `nginx` upon installation, so I am able to access it in `https://11.22.33.44/jenkins`

I want to also be able to access port `50000` on the master for remote `jnlp` connections (i.e. initiated outside the cluster).

If I understand correctly, using this [value](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml#L183) I can create a (secondary I assume) load balancer for the service of the agent (i.e. the one pertaining to port `50000`.).

My question is how to restrict this secondary load balancer given that I see only one [value](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml#L198), related to load balancer source ip ranges.

What if I have different requirements in terms of source IP ranges for

a) the `jenkins` ui (port `443`)

b) the `jenkins` jnlp protocol (port `50000`)

Comment: are you running your k8s in cloud?

Comment: yes in Google Kubernetes Engine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. You can create a secondary load balancer for the service of the agent.

And to restrict secondary load balancer with separate source IP ranges you need to modify the charts a little. You can achieve it following steps bellow:

1. Add `slaveLoadBalancerSourceRanges` variable (it doesn't necessarily have to be called like this) to `values.yaml` file and now you have two variables: `slaveLoadBalancerSourceRanges` and `loadBalancerSourceRanges` that you can set to any values you like (you can do it now).
2. Notice these few lines [in jenkins-master-svc.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/templates/jenkins-master-svc.yaml#L37-L40) responsible for setting `loadBalancerSourceRanges`:

   ```
   {{- if .Values.master.loadBalancerSourceRanges }}
     loadBalancerSourceRanges:
   {{ toYaml .Values.master.loadBalancerSourceRanges | indent 4 }}
   {{- end }}
   ```
3. Modify previously noticed lines to use newly created variable:

   ```
   {{- if .Values.master.slaveLoadBalancerSourceRanges }}
     loadBalancerSourceRanges:
   {{ toYaml .Values.master.slaveLoadBalancerSourceRanges | indent 4 }}
   {{- end }}
   ```
4. Paste these lines [to jenkins-agent-svc.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/templates/jenkins-agent-svc.yaml#L28-L29) (between these two highlighted lines )
5. Deploy these changes to kubernetes.

Let me know it if was useful.